# Dimension of the vector space generated by the n-fold composition of an endomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $f\in End(V)$. For $n = 0,1,2...$Let $f^n$ denote the n-fold composition of  $f$ with itself i.e    $f^0=Id$, $f^1=f$, $f^n=f^{n-1}\circ f$

Show that $dim(span\{f^n | n\in\ \mathbb{N}\})\leq dim(V)$

I'm having some difficulties with this problem, I was told that an argument by induction using Caley-Hamilton could work but I don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Cayley-Hamilton tells you that $f$ satisfies a polynomial equation of degree $n = \dim V$, that is $f^n + a_{n-1} f^{n-1} + \ldots + a_1 f + a_0 = 0$. This polynomial relation in $f$ can be viewed as a linear dependence of $id = f^0, f, f^2, \ldots, f^{n}$ -- it allows you to express $f^n$ in terms of $f^k$ for $k<n$. Multiply the Cayley-Hamilton relation by $f$ to get linear dependence between higher powers.